# Error when trying to exit terminal emulator

Tags: linux, terminal, zsh

### Background

I run `zsh` by default, and spend most of my day logged into a terminal. My workstation and all of the servers I interact with on a daily basis are Linux-based, and I either use `zsh` or `bash` on all of my accounts, depending on the machine. I prefer key commands over using a mouse, so I generally type `exit` to close a terminal window when I don't need it anymore.

### Problem

Closing a terminal window with `exit` has never failed, until today. When trying to close the window, I got this error:

```
% exit
exit:55: maximum nested function level reached
```

I think I understand the error itself, that the terminal is somehow experiencing a non-terminating recursive call. But what I don't understand is how `exit` caused this, and what I did to make it happen.

### How I Got Here

I opened this window to shell into a server. I did some work there, and then exited that session. I then used `wget` to pull down an ISO image, and I used `dd` to write it to an external hard drive. After that finished, I typed `exit` to close the terminal window, and got the above error.

### Troubleshooting Steps Taken

1. I updated my system to see if that might be the problem.
2. I searched for anyone else having this error, but they all seemed to be related to actual recursion calls, not build-in commands executed by themselves.
3. I opened a new terminal window, typed `exit` at the prompt, and had no problem.
4. I opened a new terminal window again, shelled into the same server I'd connected to earlier, poked around a bit, typed `exit` at the prompt, and had no problem.
5. I opened a new terminal window again, shelled into the same server again, exited, then I pulled down the same ISO image as before, wrote it to `/dev/null/`, typed `exit` at the prompt, and had no problem.

I'm at a loss as to what happened in the first terminal. Of course I can just close the window, but what I don't understand is why this happened. Any help?

Comment: Any chance you had sourced any files in the first one, perhaps something that tried to alias `exit` or something like that?

Comment: @EricRenouf that's a great thought, but I checked again to be sure, and no, I didn't alias anything in that session.

Comment: The first thing I would check is the output of `whence -f exit`; It should say "exit is a shell builtin". The next step would be checking if either of the functions `TRAPEXIT` or `zshexit` are defined (e.g. `whence -v TRAPEXIT zshexit`). If this turns up empty, you could check if the array `zshexit_functions` contains anything: `echo $zshexit_functions`. If it does it returns a list of function names.

Comment: @Adaephon here's the results: `% whence -f exit` (\n) `exit` (\n) `% whence -v TRAPEXIT zshexit` (\n) `TRAPEXIT not found` (\n) `zshexit not found` (\n) `% echo $zshexit_functions` (\n) (\n) `%`

Comment: @JonathanLandrum Oh, it should have been `whence -v exit` for the first test. Sorry, my bad. At least it does not seem to be a function.

Comment: @Adaephon ah. But yes, `$zshexit_functions` is indeed unset.